# String is not convertible from Dictionary<String,AnyObject> Error in Swift

Tags: swift

I've been battling this for too long. I have no idea

```
var a : [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    [
        "this":12
    ]
]

var b = "this"

func findAllKV(array: [[String:AnyObject]], key: String, value: AnyObject) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
    var all : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    for dict in array {
        if dict[key] == value {
            all.append(dict)
        }
    }
    return all
}


findAllKV(a, b, 12)
```

I'm just trying to make a function that searches though an array of dictionaries and finds all with the matching key value

Comment: This doesn't work either: `a.filter({$0[b] == 12})`

Comment: `dict[key]` is an optional. Pretty sure there are questions about dictionary lookup, downcasting, and unwrapping optionals already.

Comment: I put a println(dict) in the for loop and got the result of [this: 12]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict[key] returns an optional value. Try unwrapping it before checking:

```
var a : [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    [
        "this":12
    ]
]

var b = "this"

func findAllKV(array: [[String:AnyObject]], key: String, value: AnyObject) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
    var all : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    for dict in array {
        if let val: AnyObject = dict[key] {
            if val === value {
                all.append(dict)
            }
        }
    }
    return all
}


var x = findAllKV(a, b, 12)
println(x) //[[this : 12 ]]
```

Comment: As it turns out, I needed to read a lot more about Optionals. What a pain! But now that I understand them, I can see it being useful. One more question: why do I need `===` and `==` doesn't work?

Comment: === checks if they reference the same instance while == checks if they are equivalent

Comment: to use == you will have to create an equality function for AnyObject that determines whether or not they are equivalent

Comment: The === check isn't required here.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one - println() helps reveal the issue:**

```
var a : [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    [
        "this":12,
        "test":13
    ],
    [
        "me":15,
        "you":16
    ]
]

var b = "you"

func findAllKV(array: [[String:AnyObject]], key: String, value: AnyObject) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
    var all : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    for dict in array {

        println(dict)
        println(dict[key])

        if let value: AnyObject = dict[key] {
            println(value)
            all += dict
        }
    }
    return all
}


findAllKV(a, b, 12)
```